# IOS application web-scraping dilemma

Tags: post, web-scraping, nsurlconnection

I have implemented a web-scraping iOS application for a service provider to get data usage information. This used to work fine using `NSURLConnection` to post the username and password to the site, and then scrape the response.

However, said service provider has recently upgraded their account website and the login step now also includes an account selection step. So you first provide a username and password, the response then includes a list of all your accounts. This is presented in a selectable list. Clicking an account causes another postback, the response is the data I want to scrape.

I am unsure how to programatically perform this second step, since no data is sent with the request, and no extra cookies are set. Each clickable account link causes a __dopostback javascript action, so it is all handled serverside. There seems no way for me to perform this postback using nsurlconnection as no data about which account was clicked is sent with the post.

Any ideas how I could get around this?